# Probability at mean for a Gaussian function pdf

Tags: probability

How to find Probability at mean  for a Gaussian function pdf?

i.e $$ P { (X = mean )}$$ for the Gaussian distribution pdf

Comment: Do you want $P(X=\mathbb EX)$ where $X$ has normal distribution? Then the answer is $0$ (as for every continuous distribution with expectation).

Comment: More generally, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a countable set, then $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard, almost impossible to hit any certain point when you are modelling absolutely continuous random variable $\xi$. I mean that probability of such event is zero. Even more, probability is zero to get into any set of zero measure. More specific if $f(\cdot)$ is the probability density function, $\lambda(\cdot)$ is the measure and $S$ is a set of zero measure $\lambda(S) = 0$ then
$$\mathrm{P}\{\xi \in S\} = \int_{S} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \le \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x) \cdot \lambda(S) = 0.$$

You can compute the probability of being close to the mean value for a normally distributed random variable $\eta \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$:
$$\mathrm{P}\{|\eta - \mathbb{E}\eta| \le \varepsilon\} = \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\mu + \varepsilon - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right) - \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\mu - \varepsilon - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right) = 2\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma\sqrt2}\right)$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$, where $\mathrm{erf}(\cdot)$ is the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). Note that $\mathrm{erf}(0) = 0$.

Comment: Had  a doubt that P (X=mean) = 1/2 for Gaussian pdf ..